# Core location alerts

Tags: iphone, ios, alert, core-location

I saw in an O'Reilly tutorial the following alerts:

1. http://answers.oreilly.com/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_rel_module=post&attach_id=125
2. http://answers.oreilly.com/uploads/monthly_10_2009/post-48-125435525931_thumb.jpg

I don't understand how to trigger these alerts. Please could you inform me? The app using ios6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the alert when access your current location , this will automatically ask when you access user current location using [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html)

```
-(void)getLocation
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    NSLog(@"eee%f",locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude);
    // Start updating location changes.
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}


- (void)startUpdatingCurrentLocation
{
    //NSLog(@"STARTUPDATELOCATION");
    // if location services are restricted do nothing
    if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied ||
        [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted )
    {
        return;
    }

    // if locationManager does not currently exist, create it
    if (!locationManager)
    {
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        [locationManager setDelegate:self];
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0f; // we don't need to be any more accurate than 10m


    }

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    // [self showCurrentLocationSpinner:YES];
}
```

Just read [CLLocationManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) for more info

Answer (score 0):

Alright, its pretty damn simple. Its called a `UIAlertView` and very common for giving notifications. They should be used for notifying the user something and not too much for interaction.

Coding wise, here is some basic setup text:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Alert Body" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
```

To show the alert:

```
[alert show];
```

If you want other button titles, you need to set the `delegate` to `self` and conform in you .h file to the `UIAlertViewDelegate`. [Here Is The Reference To The Delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html) and you basically want to implement the `clickedButtonAtIndex:` method and work with the indexes to find out which button the user pressed and perform actions.

[Do not misuse alert views.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW41)